# Fundamental Group of Connected Sum of $n$ Tori with point removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I know that the connected sum of two tori can be found using the polygonal presentation of this surface and the Van-Kampen theorem. My questions is:

> What is the fundamental group of a connected sum of a two tori with a point removed.

Looking at the polygonal presentation of the connected two tori with point removed, I see that this deformation retracts to the boundary of the polygonal region. Thus, I think that the fundamental group would be the wedge sum of 4 circles. Is this correct?

If possible, I would also like to know:

> What is the fundamental group of the connected sum of a two tori, but with two points removed.

If my reasoning for the first questions is correct, I think that this fundamental group should be the wedge sum of 5 circles. Is this correct?

Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have the right idea. But your use of the terminology is incorrect.

In the case of a surface $S$ which is the connected sum of two tori with one point removed, you should *not* say that "the fundamental group would be the wedge sum of 4 circles". A group and a space are different kinds of mathematical objects, and you have to be more careful with your terminology. Instead you should say first that $S$ deformation retracts to the wedge sum of 4 circles. And what follows next is that the fundamental group of $S$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a wedge sum of 4 circles (which is isomorphic to a free group of rank 4).

Similarly, when $S$ is the connected sum of two tori with two points removed, you should say first that $S$ deformation restrcts to the wedge sum of 5 cicles, and what follows next is that the fundamental group of $S$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a wedge sum of 5 circles (which is isomorphic to a free group of rank 5).

Comment: Yes, thank you the comments. I will be more careful with the terminology in the future.