# Fundamental group of the connected sum of $n$ tori with $m$ points removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

I have read through this answer: [Fundamental Group of Connected Sum of $n$ Tori with point removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451097/fundamental-group-of-connected-sum-of-n-tori-with-point-removed), which deals with the special case of removing a single point. I wish to generalize this. Would anyone be able to nudge me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the polygonal representation of your n-holed torus.

Put your $k$ "missing" points in a small disk around the center of your $4n$-gon.

Draw a circle $S_1$ around the $k$ deleted points; draw a circle $S_2$ outside that.

Then the portion of the figure outside $S_1$ is topologically an $n$-holed torus with $1$ point removed, so you can use the previous computation to figure out generators and relations for its fundamental group.

The portion INSIDE $S_2$ is a disk with $k$ holes; you can compute $\pi_1$ for that as well. And then you can use Seifert-van Kampen to compute $\pi_1$ of the union of the two.